# How to avoid `Enter passphrase for /root/.ssh/id_rsa` in creating docker image

Tags: git, docker, ssh, bitbucket

I'm creating a docker image and I need to access bitbucket in the container.

I have uploaded my ssh public key into bitbucket and I have private key in my local, and my I can successfully access bitbucket from local.

Below is my Dockerfile

```
FROM an-image-built-by-company

ENV CGO_ENABLED=1

RUN yum install -y \
    make \
    wget \
    git \
    bash \
    curl \
    vim

WORKDIR /code
COPY . /code

RUN git config --global --add url."ssh://git@bitbucket.oci.oraclecorp.com:7999".insteadOf "https://bitbucket.oci.oraclecorp.com/scm" && \
    mkdir /root/.ssh && \
    mv /code/id_rsa ~/.ssh/id_rsa && \
    chmod 400 ~/.ssh/id_rsa && \
    eval $(ssh-agent) && \
    ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

I copied my local id_rsa file into the contianer, and start the ssh-agent and wanted to add the private key by ssh-add. However, the image build keeps failing with the prompt `Enter passphrase for /root/.ssh/id_rsa`.

```
 > [5/5] RUN git config --global --add url."ssh://git@bitbucket.oci.oraclecorp.com:7999".insteadOf "https://bitbucket.oci.oraclecorp.com/scm" &&     mkdir /root/.ssh &&     mv /code/id_rsa ~/.ssh/id_rsa &&     chmod 400 ~/.ssh/id_rsa &&     eval $(ssh-agent) &&     ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa:
#9 0.278 Agent pid 16
#9 0.282 Enter passphrase for /root/.ssh/id_rsa: 
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c git config --global --add url."ssh://git@bitbucket.oci.oraclecorp.com:7999".insteadOf "https://bitbucket.oci.oraclecorp.com/scm" &&     mkdir /root/.ssh &&     mv /code/id_rsa ~/.ssh/id_rsa &&     chmod 400 ~/.ssh/id_rsa &&     eval $(ssh-agent) &&     ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa]: exit code: 1
make: *** [image] Error 1
```

Why is it asking the passphrase? I tried the same command locally it just added my identity and didn't ask any passphrase.

For reference, I've tried  `eval $(ssh-agent`, eval `ssh-agent -s` but none of them worked.

There's one time the image build with the same Dockerfile succeeded and I don't konw why, the only difference I see is in the /root/.ssh in the container there's a `known_hosts` file, I don't even know how that got created.

Please advise what I'm missing here.

-- Update --

I created a new key and pressed Enter to skip passphrase, but I'm still running into the same issue while building the image. (It works fine in my local machine)

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "my-email-address"
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/Users/myname/.ssh/id_rsa):
/Users/myname/.ssh/id_rsa already exists.
Overwrite (y/n)? y
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
```

Comment: Same issue. I'd like to enter the passphrase, but instead, it's exiting with no chance... Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

> Why is it asking the passphrase?

Because the private SSH key has been encrypted, protected by a passphrase at its creation (`ssh-keygen`)

Using a passphrase-less key would be more convenient in your case.

Comment: I recreated a new pair of keys and I pressed Enter for passphrase key but unfortunately I'm still getting the same error while building the image. I added the command used to created new keys in my question.

Comment: @displayH Did you properly register the new public key to your profile at `bitbucket.oci.oraclecorp.com`?

Comment: I followed the instructions here https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/set-up-an-ssh-key/ to upload the new public key to my profile. I realized I never received confirmation email from bitbucket. But I can still access bitbucket from local

Comment: @displayH the check in step 3 work? `ssh -T git@bitbucket.oci.oraclecorp.com:9999`. Don't forget those instructions were originally for bitbucket.org. But you seem to be working with a custom BitBucket server at `bitbucket.oci.oraclecorp.com`, with a custom remote port 9999.